# JavaScript - 'No Access Control Allow Origin' header' despite one being present

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a simple PHP file that performs a MySQL query and returns a result.

At the top of the PHP file, I have this code:

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

?>
```

I know that this is working as if I were to inspect in Chrome, if I look at the request headers that come back in the 'Network' tab I can see the header was set successfully.

Now I make the call from my JavaScript file on another domain using jQuery:

```
var getMyResults = $.ajax({
    url: "http://mydomain.uk/myphpfile.php",
    data: {something: "someData"},
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: "GET"
});
```

Every single time I run this code from the JavaScript file I get the follow error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mydomain.uk/myphpfile.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myotherdomaincallingthefile.uk' is therefore not allowed access.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You may be having the same problem as me, is there a redirect first before that header is shown? Like from non-www to www for example

Comment: @t3chguy There is a `require_once` beneath the headers but no, the headers are set right at the top of the page. The file is on a subdomain from the main domain, api.mydomain.com

Comment: try your URL in http://redirectcheck.com/ and check for any weird redirect behaviour, Chrome would automatically follow the redirect and then you'd get the final headers, but Ajax only checks for the target header in the first response.

Comment: @Quentin The first code sample is the file that pulls data from the database, basically the API file. The code sample below is the JavaScript application that pulls data from that API file

Comment: @t3chguy Looks like something is going on! 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' in the check, does that mean anything to you?

Comment: it means you'll have to find that redirect and either add the header via the .htaccess file or whatever is causing it, or use the Final URL in your Ajax call. I was right in the assumption of it being a redirect issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a redirect going on before you get to the final page, which sends the header, locate it; if it is in .htaccess you can add this to the .htaccess file:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</ifModule>
```

or your other option is in your Ajax call to use the final URL, which would supply the headers without any redirects in the way.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of investigation I found the issue with the help of t3chguy in the comments.

My AJAX request URL: "http://mydomain.uk/directory"
Correct, working cross origin AJAX: "http://mydomain.uk/directory/"

A single extra "/" fixed the issue.

**Why?**

With the help of http://redirectcheck.com/ I saw that without the '/' Apache was making a redirect which meant that the cross origin header wasn't present on that initial request, hence the error.

Comment: You probably have some Apache code adding a trailing slash to all Folder Requests.

Comment: @t3chguy Is that bad, should I find and change that?

Comment: Your own preference, in my opinion its marginally better for SEO, so Google has no chance of Indexing both `~/directory` and `~/directory/`

Comment: No probs, I'd appreciate an up-vote or something on my answer below ;)